# Krusader : is it possible to connect to remote server with identity file?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, private-key

I am using https://krusader.org/ in Ubuntu.
Do you know if it possible to connect using a private SSH key (pem/ppk file)? I cannot find documentation about that.

Answer (score 7):

I found an answer using `~/.ssh/config` file.
Essentially, (create &) edit the above file to include text which looks something like:

```
Host alias_name
    User user
    HostName host.com
    IdentityFile key.pem
```

See [link](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) for details.

Then, tell Krusader (or ssh in terminal) to connect to alias_name without password or user information.

Ubuntu is FUN!

Comment: Sorry, where to tell Krusader to use this  alias?

Comment: Well, my krusader does not recognize my config.

Comment: @visoft open terminal and type ssh <alias_name>, it might lead you to what is wrong. Mine was also not working in Krusader at first, but in terminal i got error that i had set wrong path to key (and when i fixed it, that i have bad permission set on key). After i fixed my errors it works flawlessly.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because there is no mention of how to actually use ssh alias config files in Krusader; as far as I can see this is not possible. 'New network connection' option only accepts host + u/n + pass. So where did you input this config in Krusader?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to refer to your `~/.ssh/config` file within krusader. It'll follow instructions made in this file automatically.
I realised jump hops that way. However I had to point to port 22 although target server was configured to another port.